# Formulas for calculating the 3D rotation angles (yaw, pitch, roll) from a disks 2D projection on the image plane.

Tags: circles, conic-sections, projection

I'm writing an image processing algorithm, which should determine the 3D rotation angles and the centre (optional) of a disk from its 2D projection (ellipse) on the image plane.

What is the relationship between the parameters (semi-minor axis, semi-major axis, centre and the angle between the semi-major axis and the horizontal axis of the image) of the ellipse and the rotation angles of the circle?

I've found [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/21173312.pdf) paper, in which the authors gave quite an extensive deduction on this topic, however I — a non-mathematician — couldn't comprehend it. Could you explain it to me?

This is how far I got:

1. I create a synthetic image of the ellipse, by rotating a circle drawn to the middle of an image by using the function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473573/rectifying-document-with-3d-rotation-at-opencv) stackowerflow topic.
2. I obtain a solid version of the elliptic curve by floodfilling it with the openCV floodFill.
3. I calculate the covariance matrix from the coordinates of the non zero pixels of the image using the numpy cov function on those coordinates.
4. From the covariance matrix I calculate (using function 4 from the previously linked [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/21173312.pdf)) the normal to the circle rotated in 3D, which is then not a unit vector (as it's longer than 1) and by calculating its angles, they don't match the original angles I used to rotate the original circle (in point 1).

Where is the mistake, how do I get the yaw pitch and roll angles?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Imagine a circular ring in space hanging over the table, with a tilt (i.e. making a angle with the plane of the table).  When you project the ring onto the table, it becomes an ellipse with a major axis equal to the diameter of the ring, and a minor axis equal to the diameter multiplied by the cosine of the angle between the plane of the ring and the plane of the table.  So, from the ellipse given, you can determine the major/minor axes and their directions, and also you can determine $\cos^{-1} \dfrac{minor}{major}$ which is the tilt angle.

Comment: This work, if the rotation of the circle in 3D is purely around the X or the Y axis, however, using yaw and pitch at the same time will rotate the ellipse around the other axis.

Comment: @valentine The projected circular disc will be an ellipse in the $xy$ plane.  Identify it (i.e. find its axes magnitudes and directions).  The direction of the minor axis determines the angle $\phi$ of the normal vector to the plane of the disc (in 3D).  The full expression for the normal is $\mathbf{n} = (\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta)$ There is only these two angles $\theta$ and $\phi$, because of the circular symmetry of the disc. The angle $\theta = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{\text{Minor Axis Length}}{\text{Major Axis Length}}$